# UPS Shipping Method Broken For Non-US Origin?

Tags: magento2

Is the Ups service broken or Magento?

```
[2016-08-24 10:00:31] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' => 
  array (
    'accept_UPS_license_agreement' => 'yes',
    '10_action' => '4',
    '13_product' => 'GNDRES',
    '14_origCountry' => 'GB',
    '15_origPostal' => 'M43 6BU',
    'origCity' => 'Manchester',
    '19_destPostal' => 'OL10 3DA',
    '22_destCountry' => 'GB',
    '23_weight' => 20,
    '47_rate_chart' => 'Customer Counter',
    '48_container' => '00',
    '49_residential' => '01',
    'weight_std' => 'lbs',
  ),
  'result' => 'UPSOnLine5%Origin postal code must have five digits.%0000
',
) {"is_exception":false} []
[2016-08-24 10:00:31] main.DEBUG: Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again or contact us and we'll try to help.: Origin postal code must have five digits. {"is_exception":false} []
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of may be to change the ip / url it is trying to connect to for the uk variant - but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in Canada, and we share the same connector for CAN/US. It seems as though you have to switch to UPS XML format... best I have found so far.

Comment: @Spyrule My store in India, so my default weight KGS. UPS for USA shipping, what i need to do with "Weight Unit"   KGS or LBS?

Comment: @zus Honestly, I have no idea.  My guess is Lbs (so KG * 2.2)

Comment: @Spyrule Bro, the shipping cost will show to the customer. The issue is, UPS standard price will show to the customer, not showing my Negotiated Price. I have enabled Negotiated price option = yes, still not shown my negotiated price.

Comment: @zus The reason why your negotiated price isn't appearing, is you need to use UPS Xml as the UPS Type, and then set your Shipper Number below. Thats the only way to get negotiated rates to appear.